# Why won't a military Dwarf work?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a dwarf in Dwarf Fortress 0.31.10 that will not take any job, and continually goes into `Individual Combat Training`.  If removed from his squad, he will remain in `No Job`, and no other dwarf in his squad has this problem.  Is there any way I can get this dwarf to work?  Note that he does labors (including Hauling and Mining) enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a known bug to me, according to the [Dwarf Fortress Forums](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=56723.0)

> Once dwarves start training in a barracks, they will never ever do any civilian work ever again. No matter what.

Comment: I know it was one, but my other military dwarves are fine.  Why this one dwarf?

Comment: have the others trained yet?

Comment: @alexanderpas Yes, more than once.

Comment: Military is just buggy. I rely on devious traps. Each more devious than the last.

Comment: @JavadocMD A pick to the face is so much more rewarding.

Comment: May have been fixed in [0.31.11](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=62202.0).

Comment: Hey look, he's mining now *that I bought another pick*

Comment: sigh... sometimes, you overook the most obvious things...

Comment: Yep, once they learn to carry weapons around, they only want to run around the fort going hup! Hup! hup!  No weenie civilian labors are good enough for the dwarven military elite.